# Track external links in SharePoint with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track external (outbound) links from my SharePoint 2007 site. However, when I add the Google Analytics Event Tracking 'OnClick' code to the href SharePoint strips it out when I save the page. Is there another way to track outbound links or a way to have the code remain in the href?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do this with jQuery in the past. On document ready, I'd look for any hyperlinks that were outside the domain and add an OnClick function.